# How do I call a function that has a nested function?

Tags: python, filter, nested-function

I am new to nested functions and want to make a call to my function below, I am trying to find if a number is prime or not using nested functions and filter. Below is my code:

```
def divides(n):
    def div(k):
        return n % k == 0
    return div

def prime(n):
    cnt=0
    res = list(filter(divides(n)(range(1,n)),range(1,n)))
    for i in res:
        if i==True:
            cnt+=1
    if cnt == 2:
        return ("It is a prime")
    else:
        return ("It is not a prime")

print(prime(5))
```

So it throws a type error because I am trying to send numbers from 1 to n as a range to the nested function. How can I call this function with two values? What is the right way to call a nested function?

Comment: Instead of `list(filter(divides(n)(range(1,n)),range(1,n)))` might you want to do something like `[divides(n)(k) for k in range(1, n)]`?

Comment: fwiw rather than using a nested function I think it'd be much simpler to just have a single function that takes two parameters...

Comment: `divides()` is not nested.

Comment: ```list(filter(divides(n), range(1,n)))``` would be the way to call it. However, this results in the program printing "It is not a prime" when called with 5, so you also have a logic error. I think what you really need is ```list(filter(divides(n), range(1,n+1)))``` since ranges are not inclusive of the right endpoint in Python.

Comment: Oops, that still doesn't work. You either need to use map rather than filter, or better yet just compute cnt as ```cnt=len(res)``` rather than iterating through the list.

Comment: @Samwise I agree, but I just wanted to understand nested functions better

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `divides(n)(range(1,n))` creates the function `divides(n)` and then right away calls it, with a full range object as argument. That range object becomes the `k` and the `n % k` fails.

You try to use the function in `filter`, which wants a function as first argument:

```
res = list(filter(divides(n)(range(1,n)),range(1,n)))
```

What you meant to do is:

```
res = list(filter(divides(n), range(1, n)))
```

Then `filter` applies the function returned by `divides(n)` to each number in that range. For your `n = 5`, you get `res = [1]`, the only divisor of 5 in that range.

What you do with `res` is also buggy and looks like you should use `range(1, n+1)`, as you're trying to find out whether there are exactly two divisors. Just check `len(res) == 2` for that.

Or instead of collecting all divisors in a list and then counting, you could just check whether there are any divisors:

```
def prime(n):
    if any(filter(divides(n), range(2, n))):
        return ("It is not a prime")
    else:
        return ("It is a prime")
```

Simpler, and has the added benefit of being able to stop early. For example, `prime(1000)` only goes as far as 2, not checking any further candidates.

Comment: I still don't understand how the value of k in the nested function is set?

Comment: Like I said: "filter applies the function returned by divides(n) to each number in that range".